# How do I wrap execl in c

Tags: c

I tried two ways:

```
void func(const char *path, const char *arg0, ...){
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, arg0);
        execl(path, arg0, args, NULL);
        va_end(args);
}
func("/bin/ls", "ls");
```

And:

```
void func(const char *path, const char *arg0, ...){
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, arg0);
        execl(path, arg0, args);
        va_end(args);
}

func("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
```

But seems non work as expected after several test...

What's wrong in my way of wrapping variable length parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't know how many arguments you'll be receiving, you'll need/want to use `execv` instead of `execl`. You'll need to walk through the arguments, retrieve a pointer to the beginning of each string, and put them into an array. You'll then pass the address of that array to `execv`.

Answer (score 0):

`execl()` is a variadic function, so this should compile.

However, it won't work.  `execl` expects each of its arguments to be a `const char *`, i.e. a pointer to a string.  A `va_list` is not such a thing.